# Manipulate a data frame - amending the last row name

Tags: r

I'm building a set of coordinates to plot on GGMAP with the code below.

```
coords <- rbind(as.matrix(rte[,7:8]),as.matrix(rte[nrow(rte),9:10])) %>% 
    as.data.frame()
```

This generates the data below.  The issue I have is with the end point (last point/row).

I'm getting an error as there is a duplicate value (9.3) - I need to rename this +0.1 of the previous value i.e. 9.4.

```
structure(list(startLon = c(-2.8812933, -2.8836377, -2.8846959, 
-2.883528, -2.8867415, -2.8878325, -2.8880098, -2.8895748, -2.8935501, 
-2.8971835, -2.8987187, -2.8989829, -2.8986408, -2.8989038, -2.897305, 
-2.8939165, -2.8932886, -2.8932332, -2.8932886, -2.891303, -2.8904392, 
-2.8896841, -2.8900902, -2.8896841, -2.8916631, -2.8908963, -2.889908, 
-2.889908, -2.8897949, -2.8877892, -2.8879832), startLat = c(53.1935042, 
53.1934807, 53.1962441, 53.1968895, 53.1943495, 53.1938296, 53.1936907, 
53.1943944, 53.1942666, 53.1939625, 53.1931411, 53.1930795, 53.1928816, 
53.1926769, 53.1893671, 53.1898796, 53.1899857, 53.1899088, 53.1899857, 
53.1903599, 53.1905145, 53.1906626, 53.1912708, 53.1906626, 53.1902482, 
53.1884563, 53.1868239, 53.1868239, 53.1866933, 53.1877751, 53.1884169
)), .Names = c("startLon", "startLat"), row.names = c("1.1", 
"1.2", "1.3", "2.1", "2.2", "2.3", "2.4", "2.5", "2.6", "2.7", 
"3.1", "3.2", "3.3", "3.4", "3.5", "4.1", "4.2", "5.1", "5.2", 
"5.3", "6.1", "6.2", "7.1", "7.2", "7.3", "7.4", "8", "9.1", 
"9.2", "9.3", "9.3"), class = "data.frame")
```

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Is the object you shared `coords` or `rte`? When do row names get introduced, and do you have a reason to use them rather than just using a column? Is the data actually wrong, (that last 9.3 is supposed to be 9.4) or are you updating it simply so it's unique?

Comment: If you just want to change it, `row.names(coords)[nrow(coords)] = "9.4"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a generic solution:

```
mx1 <- matrix(1:10, 5, dimnames=list(c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2"), NULL))
mx1 %>% `row.names<-`(make.unique(row.names(.))) %>% as.data.frame
```

Produces:

```
    V1 V2
1    1  6
1.1  2  7
1.2  3  8
2    4  9
2.1  5 10
```

Comment: I think you should mention where did you get that pipes from too.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, don't you know, "that isn't a pipe"?  Also, OP was using it so I typically don't show packages that the OP is implicitly including.

Comment: Oh I didn't see OP was using that thing too.